# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver, when REST try connecting to DB

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc

I running Java REST project (IDEA with Maven framework support), deploy successfully, 
but when I call service, I´m getting a strange SQLException:
"SQL exception occured: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hh_parser"

I have dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>mysql</groupId>
          <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
          <version>8.0.7-dmr</version>
</dependency>
```

and [mysql-connector-java added in WEB-INF/lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYwYo.png)

and mysql-connector-java-8.0.7.jar added in e:\tomcat\lib\

but it does not help me!

If I comment on the use of the DB, the REST service works fine.

Who knows what to do? This is a dead end! Here are full of the same questions without answers.

Comment: Where do you deploy your application?? Does it work fine in your local env?

Comment: I deploy it in IDEA+tomcat+mysql. Yes, everything works fine, except for connect to DB.

Comment: How do you access the data source? Via JNDI lookup or do you create it directly?

Comment: I think directly: con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hh_parser","rootpwd", "123");    If I use this connect from public static void main() - it working!

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you don't register your Driver with your application.

If you have written like this

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hh_‌​parser","rootpwd", "123");
```

try the below

```
Class.forName("path.to.your.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hh_‌​parser","rootpwd", "123");
```

or

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver ());
```

Comment: I try: DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hh_parser?serverTimezone=UTC","rootpwd", "123");    and Its help me!

Comment: What does that mean? Are you going to try or have you already tried?

Comment: Early I try: Class.forName("path.to.your.Driver");, but its doesnt work.                       Working with: DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver()); Thanks you!

Comment: @AnatolyBelov You should never call `DriverManager.registerDriver` yourself, that method is for JDBC drivers to register themselves. Also not that Connector/J 8 is still in development, you might be better off using the 5.1.x versions.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are using the correct version of the MySQL Connector/J jar, you need to add the jar both to your CLASSPATH environment variable and also to TOMCAT_HOME\lib folder.

As per the documentation available [here](https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/connector-j-8.0-en.a4.pdf), you need to have these settings done so as to work with MySQL JDBC connectivity.

> You can set the CLASSPATH environment variable under Unix, Linux, or OS X either locally for a user within the user's `.profile`, `.login` or other login file, or you can also set it globally by editing the global `/etc/profile` file.
>
> For example, add the `Connector/J` driver to your `CLASSPATH` using one of the following forms, depending on your command shell:
>
> ```
>   # Bourne-compatible shell (sh, ksh, bash, zsh):
>     shell> export CLASSPATH=/path/mysql-connector-java-ver-bin.jar:$CLASSPATH
>
>   # C shell (csh, tcsh):
>     shell> setenv CLASSPATH /path/mysql-connector-java-ver-bin.jar:$CLASSPATH
> ```
>
> For Windows platforms, you set the environment variable through the System Control Panel. To use MySQL Connector/J with an application server such as GlassFish, Tomcat, or JBoss, read your vendor's documentation for more information on how to configure third-party class libraries, as most application servers ignore the CLASSPATH environment variable.
>
> If you are developing servlets or JSPs, and your application server is J2EE-compliant, you can put the driver's `.jar` file in the `WEB-INF/lib` subdirectory of your webapp, as this is a standard location for third party class libraries in J2EE web applications.